# Allow SKU adjustments based on only one Attribute in Ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have a product where customers can select six different flavors from six individual select boxes (there are eleven flavors listed in each box), and one other select box where they can select their package size (2 oz packs vs 5 oz packs). It's a food product that comes in two package sizes; on this product page they are ordering a mixed case and their size selection determines whether they are ordering a case of 2ox bags or a case of 5oz bags.

I need to adjust the SKU to MIXED-2OZ or MIXED-5OZ based on the "size" selected by the shopper, but I do not want the flavors to come into play for this SKU adjustment. How can I exclude the flavors attributes/options from the Adjustments tab so that only the size will affect the SKU?

I suppose one workaround would be to set a SKU for each size/flavor combination, but we would be talking about hundreds of available combinations. The sheer number of available combinations is also causing my Adjustments tab to timeout, as is described here: http://drupal.org/node/375019.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with one-size-fits-all is that there are always use cases that cannot be handled. Have you thought about using two product kits, one for each size, and mixing the flavors of the items in the kits? Might be easier to find a work-around.

Comment: @Triskelion would product kits allow the end-user to select their flavors on that one page? If so, that would probably be the best way to go for me. As it stands right now, I believe I have close to 100,000 possible combinations that would need SKUs haha.

Comment: You might need some customization. I have no direct experience with product kits but it seems logical if you are grouping products. The examples I have seen are rather hard-wired to a selection. All I can say is give it a try. Better than 100,000 SKU's.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. To keep things simple, and to avoid a lot of additional programming, I think I will simply offer two separate Mixed Case SKUs (one for 5oz and one for 2oz) and use the primary SKU for each one. That will give me the end result I need, and I can create a little banner or link on each of those product pages to tell the shopper about the existence of the other available size. Thanks!